# How to find the first character in a given string, that appears only once

Tags: java, string, algorithm

This is an interview question. Find the first character in a given string, that appears only once (I suppose the solution should be in Java).

For example:

```
"babcbcd" -> 'a' // both 'a' and 'd' appear only once but 'a' appears before 'd'
```

The trivial solution is

- build a *map* (e.g. `HashMap`): char -> number of its appearances in the string;
- scan the string and test string characters against the *map* until the *value* of the character is 1.

Does it make sense? What is the best *map* implementation? Is there any better, more efficient solution?

Comment: *"Is there any better, more efficient solution?"* What do *you* think?

Comment: _Is there any better, more efficient solution?_ I don't think so.

Comment: you could keep a priority queue and pop the top off and check if it's 1.

Comment: @AramKocharyan what do you use for the priority? How is it better than the double-iteration with a hashmap?

Comment: I think this is typically the kind of questions are you must first refine the requirements. For instance: is memory or cpu time more important. I also think, it's a bit off-topic here (http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version in Haskell.

```
import Data.List (elemIndices)
firstSingle str = take 1 [a | a <- str, length (elemIndices a str) == 1]
```

*Main Data.List> firstSingle "babcbcd"
"a"

Comment: @RyanStewart ...you inspired me ;)

Comment: lol, and vice versa. Check out [my update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14923631/839646). I kept thinking there must be a much simpler way.

Comment: @RyanStewart nice. beat you by one character (not counting spaces) ;) oh, but there's the import, oh well

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you could use a [`LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to count how many times each character appears in the string. Since `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order, you could then iterate over its entries to find the first character that appears exactly once.

Under reasonable assumptions, this would give an `O(n)` solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I were interviewing, I'd be hoping for (though not necessarily expecting) something like this:

```
def string = 'babcbcd'
def singles = string.toList().groupBy{ it }.findAll{ it.value.size() == 1 }.collect{ it.key }
println "First char that appears once: " + string.find{ singles.contains it }
```

The key is the middle line. It takes the string as a list of characters, [groups the list](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#groupBy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) by character so you can filter out anything that didn't happen exactly once, and finally yields the list of characters that occurred once. Then we just search the string for the first character that's in that list.

It's Groovy because it's impossible to be that elegant in Java. Maybe once JDK 8 finally makes it...

**Update:** A more succinct version, inspired by [@groovy's Haskell solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14925583/839646). I'm almost embarrassed by the clumsiness of my first one now :)

```
def firstUnique(seq) { seq.findAll{ seq.count(it) == 1 }.first() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one pass of the original string: make a linked hash map, storing the counts of the character that you found so far. Then go through the map entries (it will be in insertion order, because it's a linked map) and stop when you see a count of one.

Answer (score 1):

you have already found a good solution, but if you want i suggest a different approach:

```
final String abc = "abcdefg....z";
boolean scanned[] = new boolean[abc.lenght()];
//set all to false ...
for(int i = 0; i<yourString.lenght(); i++){
    char c = yourString.charAt(i);
    if(!scanned[abc.indexOf(c)]){
        for(int j=i+1; j<yourString.lenght(); j++)
            if(yourString.charAt(i) == c){ // founded another
                scanned[abc.indexOf(c)] = true;
                break;
            }
        if(!scanned[abc.indexOf(c)])
            return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above solutions require O(n) memory.In order to do it in O(1) memory you could run a for loop for all characters( in ASCII there are 128)and count the number of appearance and the first appearance and then find the fisrt non-repeated char. Time complexity O(128|s|).

```
int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
char ans=' '; //any initialization 
for ( i=0; i<128;i++){
    int count=0,first=-1;
    for(j=0;j<s.length();j++){
         if(s.charAt(j)==(char)(i)) count++;
         if(count==1) first=j;
         if(count>1) break;
    }
    if(count==1 && min>first){
         first=min;ans=s.charAt(first);
    }
}
if(min!=Integer.MAX_VALUE) System.out.println(ans);
else System.out.println("No such char found");
```

Comment: In unicode, there are a lot more than 256 characters. Your solution is not really that much better memory-wise than the linked hash maps. Yes, you don't have the administrative overhead of maintaining the map structure, but both your solution and the hashmaps require an `Integer` counter for every possible character in the worst case. Even worse: The hashmaps only require one for each character that occurs, while yours requires one for each character in the alphabet - a lot for large alphabets like unicode.

Comment: @us2012: Look how I have done it in O(1) memory. Ans yes, It should have been ASCII . Thank you. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `String` consists only of a-z characters, you could use a queue for the characters seen so far and keep count.

```
public static String findFirstLetterThatAppearsOnceInString(String str) {
    int[] seenCount = new int[26];
    int[] queue = new int[26];
    int queueSize = 0;
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) { // Iterate over the input characters
        int i = c-'a';
        if (seenCount[i]<2) {
            seenCount[i]++;
            // If seen for the first time, store it in queue
            if (seenCount[i]==1) queue[queueSize++]=i;
        }
    }
    for (int qi=0;qi<queueSize;qi++) if (seenCount[queue[qi]]==1) return (char)(queue[qi]+'a')+"";
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, non-map solution, assuming no unicode:

```
public String firstLonelyChar(String input)
{
    while(input.length() > 0)
    {
        int curLength = input.length();
        String first = String.valueOf(input.charAt(0));
        input = input.replaceAll(first, "");
        if(input.length() == curLength - 1)
            return first;
    }
    return null;
}
```