# Time complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've been doing some reading on time complexity, and I've got the basics covered. To reinforce the concept, I took a look at an answer I recently gave here on SO. The question is now closed, for reason, but that's not the point. I can't figure out what the complexity of my answer is, and the question was closed before I could get any useful feedback.

[The task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14922454/752320) was to find the first unique character in a string. My answer was something simple:

```
public String firstLonelyChar(String input)
{
    while(input.length() > 0)
    {
        int curLength = input.length();
        String first = String.valueOf(input.charAt(0));
        input = input.replaceAll(first, "");
        if(input.length() == curLength - 1)
            return first;
    }
    return null;
}
```

[Link to an ideone example](http://ideone.com/qljw7i)

My first thought was that since it looks at each character, then looks at each again during `replaceAll()`, it would be O(n^2).

However, it got me to thinking about the way it actually works. For each character examined, it then removes all instances of that character in the string. So `n` is constantly shrinking. How does that factor into it? Does that make it O(log n), or is there something I'm not seeing?

**What I'm asking:**

What is the time complexity of the algorithm as written, and why?

**What I'm not asking:**

I'm not looking for suggestions to improve it. I get that there are probably better ways to do this. I'm trying to understand the concept of time complexity better, not find the best solution.

Comment: The length of the input string, I'd imagine.

Comment: I think this depends on a number of things: 1) does `length()` have to count every character in the string each time, or is the length stored separately so it can be returned without a linear scan? 2) If `length()` is linear, do we at least remember the result for subsequent calls? 3) What kind of memory management is used by the class - is erasing a character a simple constant-time operation, or does it require a linear re-copy of the remainder of the string? 4) When, if ever, do cumulative erasures cause reallocation and copy? And so on...

Comment: @twalberg: I think a safe assumption is that `replaceAll` must scan the entire string, since that is the "standard" implementation, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @recursive Right - `replaceAll` certainly must scan the entire string to look for matches, but the question was more for the actual erasure and how it's handled - I can think of three equally effective methods to write `replaceAll` off the top of my head, but they're not equivalent in efficiency (copy non-erased characters to temp string and copy back, or shift the string tail left on each erasure, or simply mark an erased character in some way to indicate "no character here")...

Comment: @twalberg: Given that it doesn't seem to be doing in-place erasure, (`input = /* ... */`) do any of your three methods have run-time complexity other linear?

Comment: @recursive That's a good point, which would eliminate one of the three methods, and the constant time method is not exactly general-purpose... So, as you mention, it's probably safe to assume that `replaceAll` is linear. I was really trying to get at the fact that, without knowing a) the language (although I'm guessing this one is Java) and b) the implementation of the various routines called, solving the complexity question is a little vague...

Comment: @twalberg Good point. For the purposes of this, let's assume `replaceAll` is linear, and the language is Java 1.7. I'm not sure how `length` works in Java, I assumed it was stored separately. I could be wrong there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worst time complexity you will have is for the string `aabb...` and so on each character repeated exactly twice. Now this depends on the size of your alphabet let's say that is `S`. Let's also annotate the length of your initial string with `L`. So for each letter you will have to iterate over the whole String. However first time you do that the String will be of size `L`, second time `L-2` and so on. Overall you will have to perform in the order of `L + (L-2) + ... + (L- S*2)` operations and that is `L*S - 2*S*(S+1)`, assuming L is more than `2*S`.

By the way if the size of your alphabet is constant, and I suppose it is, the complexity of your code is `O(L)`(though with a big constant).

Answer (score 1):

The worst case is `O(n^2)` where n is the length of the input string.  Imagine the case where every character is doubled except the last one, like "aabbccddeeffg".  Then there are n/2 loop iterations, and each call to `replaceAll` has to scan the entire remaining string, which is also proportional to `n`.

Edit: As Ivaylo points out, if the size of your alphabet is constant, it's technically `O(n)` since you never consider any character more than once.

Comment: I don't think it is `N^2` the complexity depends on the size of the alphabet - he will never consider a character more than once so it is more of the order of `L * S` where L is the length and `S` is the size of the alphabet. In fact if we assume S is constant the complexity is only `O(N)`.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: That's a good point.  In the case of the entire unicode character set, `N^2` still may be a tighter bound though.  I'll make a note in my answer reflecting it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's mark:

m = number of unique letters in the word 
n = input length

This is the complexity calculation: 
The main loop goes at most **m** times, because there are m different letters,

the .Replaceall checks at most O(n) comparisons in each cycle.

**the total is: O(m*n)**

an example for O(m*n) cycle is: input = aabbccdd,

m=4, n=8

the algorithm stages:

```
1. input = aabbccdd, complex - 8
2. input = bbccdd, complex = 6
3. input = ccdd, complex = 4
4. input = dd, complex = 2
```

total = 8+6+4+2 = 20 = O(m*n)

Comment: It's looking for the first unique character, not the first non-unique. Your example string would stop at 'a'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I changed the example. The complexity calculation is still valid though.

Answer (score 1):

Let `m` be the size of your alphabet, and let `n` be the length of your string. The worse case would be to uniformly distribute your string's characters between the alphabet letters, meaning you'll have `n / m` characters for each letter in your alphabet, let's mark this quantity with `q`. For example, the string `aabbccddeeffgghh` is the uniformly distribution of `16` characters between the letters `a-h`, so here `n=16` and `m=8` and you have `q=2` characters for each letter.

Now, your algorithm is actually going over the letters of the alphabet (it just uses the order which they appear in the string), and for each iteration it has to go over the length of the string (`n`) and shrink it by `q` (`n -= q`). So over all the number of operation you do in the worst case are:

```
s = n + n-(1*q) + ... + n-((m-1)*q)
```

You can see that `s` is the sum of the first `m` elements of the arithmetic series:

```
s = (n + n-((m-1)*q) * m / 2 =  
    (n + n-((m-1)*(n/m)) * m / 2 ~ n * m / 2
```